# Acetylation reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds

In the Friedel - Crafts acetylation of bromobenzene, how is it possible to obtain a black-coloured product?

When the acetic anhydride was slowly added to the reactants - $\ce{AlCl3}$, DCM, bromobenzene - a small, hard, yellow lump formed.

Would this be $\ce{AlCl3}$?

When the acetic anhydride was added, the reflux was initiated. The lump appeared to disappear, leaving behind a dark red solution.

However, when the reflux was turned off, the solution appeared black. I'm trying to think of potential products, such as ortho and para bromobenzene or acetic acid or $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ but why so black?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume "DCM" represents dichloromethane, if so...

There is an old paper that describes the formation of a low molecular weight polymer from the double Friedel-Crafts alkylation of benzene by dichloromethane. That's probably what's happening in your reaction as a minor pathway.  The dissolved polymer and tar is what's producing your black solution.

I actually ran that reaction once, I wanted to prepare that polymer.  It didn't work for me, but at the end, after the aluminum chloride had been removed, I did have a dark solution.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ron . Can you link that paper to me?  When you say ''tar'', what do you mean?

Comment: @Edward  I looked for a link before I posted and couldn't find one, the paper may be to old for an on-line citation to exist.  I'm guessing it was Journal of the Amer. Chem. Soc., maybe the 1940s or 50's.  If someone searches Chemical Abstracts with the terms Friedel-Crafts, dichoromethane, benzene, polymer, I think you'd find it.  When I rotovap'd the black liquid down, up wound up with a tar-like solid.  I wasn't able to isolate a clean, low-molecular weight polymer (oligomer) like the paper described.  I figured the tar was just a mess of higher MW polymers.

Comment: Okay. I was confused by a further two things. The addition of half-saturated NaCl - does that reduce the surface tension thereby allowing the organic droplet to ''fall'' as such?        And washing with water can remove AlCl3 by way of Al(OH)3 , H+ and Cl- ions...but why is HCl gas not produced?

Comment: And the bridge between the two benzenes? Would that be the culmination of SN1?

Comment: "half-saturated NaCl" - this must be in the product isolation step?.  Organics are less soluble in saltwater than they are in pure water, so less of the product remains in the aqueous layer and more goes into the organic layer during extraction. 2) HCl is generated during the reaction.  When the AlCl3 reacts with the anhydride and aromatic, 3 equivalents of HCl are generated along with aluminum salts containing the unreacted part of the acetic anhydride molecule - the acetate.  **If** there is any excess AlCl3 remaining after the reaction is complete, it will generate HCl when mixed with water

Comment: The bridge is the result of CH2Cl2 undergoing 2 Friedel-Crafts **alkylations** with 2 aromatic rings.  While it is not a true SN1, the Friedel-Crafts alkylation does involve a carbocation-AlCl3 complex.

Comment: yes, I understand that 3HCl are formed during the reaction, but when water is used to wash the organic product, why isn't HCl gas produced?

Comment: Typically, only a small excess of AlCl3 is used.  In this case, there will be a small amount of AlCl3 remaining after the reaction.  On contact with water during workup, HCl will be generated, but only a small amount.  It will probably just stay dissolved in the aqueous layer (test it with a pH strip).

Comment: Hi ron. I was wondering, in the mechanism for the acetylation reaction, how is HCl produced? I know it's produced during the hydrolysis step, but before that? Is there even a mechanism for this?

Comment: I see that you've asked this as a separate question; that was probably the best way to go.  BTW, if the above answer and comments were helpful, please consider marking the question as accepted. Thanks!